# unable to attach client process to postgresql server using gdb

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, postgresql, gdb

I am working with PostgreSQL 9.3.4 source using Eclipse IDE in ubuntu 14.04. I am facing a problem in attaching client process to postgresql server using gdb to debug. When I start the postmaster then I connect to it from client on a terminal. It works fine. Queries get responses. When I run debug config from eclipse then select postgres process id from list I get error saying

Can't find a source file at "/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19/socket/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/recv.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

After this when I send any query from client, it just stucks. No response comes. After attaching gdb to client process, client does not get any response from postgres server. One thing to note is that I was able to debug properly till yesterday. But now it is not working. I tried reinstalling but did not help. How could I fix this issue? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

solution which worked for me:

1. ./configure --prefix=$HOME/project --enable-depend --enable-cassert --enable-debug
2. in eclipse: Make Target: install
3. attach client process to application